# Elixir и unicode

Tags: sqlalchemy

Добрый день.

Перехожу на Flask, чему несказанно рад :)
В качестве ORM выбрал SQLAlchemy
В качестве wrapper'а очень понравился [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de)

**Однако есть проблема**: русские буковки отказываются заходить без применения .decode('utf-8')
Обрабатывать руками каждый запрос не очень-то хочется, благо что на том же Flask-SQLAlchemy все прекрасно заходит.

**Вопрос**: наверняка ведь где-то какая-то настройка есть, которую я упустил?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ах, волшебный Хэш-Код :)
Написал вопрос и сам тут же разобрался:

Строка в базу приходила из файла, где отстутствовало явное указание на utf: u''
Теперь все в порядке. Надеюсь, кому-нибудь пригодится!